# How to identify devices generating the majority of the network traffic over a certain period?

Tags: networking, snmp, mib, network-traffic, traffic-measurement

How to identify devices generating most of the network traffic over a certain period of time using SNMP queries to objects of MIB-II.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to use RFC 2863 (IF-MIB)? If yes, then I recommend to use ifOutOctets (1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.16) to monitor number of outgoing octets per interface. I do not see how MIB-II could help in this task. Does it help?